# Serialize canvas content to ArrayBuffer and deserialize again

Tags: javascript, html, serialization, html5-canvas, arraybuffer

I have two canvases, and I want to pass the content of canvas1, serialize it to an ArrayBuffer, and then load it in canvas2. In the future I will send the canvas1 content to the server, process it, and return it to canvas2, but right now I just want to serialize and deserialize it.

I found this way of getting the canvas info in bytes:

```
var img1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 400, 320);
var binary = new Uint8Array(img1.data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < img1.data.length; i++) {
    binary[i] = img1.data[i];
}
```

And also found this way of set the information to a `Image` object:

```
var blob = new Blob( [binary], { type: "image/png" } );
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
var img = new Image();
img.src = imageUrl;
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Which would be the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The ImageData you get from `getImageData()` is already using an ArrayBuffer (used by the `Uint8ClampedArray` view). Just grab it and send it:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
var buffer = imageData.data.buffer;  // ArrayBuffer
```

To set it again:

```
var imageData = context.createImageData(w, h);
imageData.data.set(incomingBuffer);
```

You probably want to consider some form of byte encoding though (such as f.ex base-64) as any byte value above 127 (ASCII) is subject to character encoding used on a system. Or make sure all steps on the trip uses the same (f.ex. UTF8).

Comment: Doesn’t work in IE because IE still uses CanvasPixelArray instead of Uint8ClampedArray (CanvasPixelArray's imageData.data has no .buffer).

Comment: @markE true, but in any other browser... (as always) :)

Comment: That darned IE!  It has gotten much better lately, though.  :)

Comment: @markE sure, it's getting there.. eventually (?) :-P The good ol' Mosaic :-]

Comment: I made it work, I had to use a Uint8Array on the "buffer" variable to make it work in "imageData". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Create an ArrayBuffer and send it into to the Uint8Array constructor, then send the buffer using websockets:

```
var img1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 400, 320);
var data=img1.data;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
var binary = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i=0; i<binary.length; i++) {
    binary[i] = data[i];
}
websocket.send(buffer);
```

Comment: I need to do it in binary.

Comment: Why? You can always convert image-to-binary on either the client-side or server-side.  The trouble is binary transport--conversion to binary is simple.

Comment: Because the connection is a websocket that accepts data in binary format. That is why I am asking to do it in binary.

Comment: Fair enough--you're constrained to a specific kind of connection on the server-side.  In your top code, you need to create an ArrayBuffer and send that through the websocket.  See my updated answer. Be sure the websocket.binaryType="arrayBuffer" because the default type is blob.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `canvas.toBlob()` instead of `context.getImageData()` if you want compact data rather than a raw [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object.

Example:

```js
const imageIn = document.querySelector('#image-in');
const imageOut = document.querySelector('#image-out');
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const imageDataByteLen = document.querySelector('#imagedata-byte-length');
const bufferByteLen = document.querySelector('#arraybuffer-byte-length');

const mimeType = 'image/png';

imageIn.addEventListener('load', () => {

  // Draw image to canvas.
  canvas.width = imageIn.width;
  canvas.height = imageIn.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(imageIn, 0, 0);

  // Convert canvas to ImageData.
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imageIn.width, imageIn.height);
  imageDataByteLen.textContent = imageData.data.byteLength + ' bytes.';

  // Convert canvas to Blob, then Blob to ArrayBuffer.
  canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      bufferByteLen.textContent = arrayBuffer.byteLength + ' bytes.';

      // Dispay Blob content in an Image.
      const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: mimeType});
      imageOut.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }, mimeType);

});
```

```html
<h1>Canvas ↔ ArrayBuffer</h1>

<h2>1. Source <code>&lt;img&gt;</code></h2>
<img id="image-in" src="https://ucarecdn.com/a0338bfa-9f88-4ce7-b53f-e6b61000df89/" crossorigin="">

<h2>2. Canvas</h2>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<h2>3. ImageData</h2>
<p id="imagedata-byte-length"></p>

<h2>4. ArrayBuffer</h2>
<p id="arraybuffer-byte-length"></p>

<h2>5. Final <code>&lt;img&gt;</code></h2>
<img id="image-out">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/jugzk15b/

Also note that images must be hosted on a service that provides CORS headers, or you'll see errors like "The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."