# how to create HTML 5 File from image (<img>) already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, filereader

Hi I have a page where I show user's profile image that is loaded like this:

$("#imgProfile").attr('src', 'http://myserver/user.png')

Now I need to submit this image using HTML 5 File API, but to do this I need to first convert my image to File API. All the samples that I saw at internet work together with input type="file", but I already have that image, I'm not choosing the image from local computer.

All the examples like this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications use File API from input type="file" element

Comment: The preview that is referring to is most likely a preview BEFORE uploading it. If it's on your server you just load it like a normal image. Creating img tags in either html or through java script.

Answer (score 3):

The file is already on your server. You can use it, as [Yair Nevet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952310/yair-nevet)'s answer says.

If you really want to make it a `File` object, maybe you can use this(I don't know if it works).

```
var getFilelikeBlobFromImageElement = (function closure() {
        var canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");

        return function(imageElement) {
                canvasElement.width = imageElement.width;
                canvasElement.height = imageElement.height;
                var canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
                canvasContext.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);

                var imageData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imageElement.width, imageElement.height).data;
                var buffer = new Uint8Array(imageData.length);
                for(var index = 0; index < imageData.length; index++)
                    buffer[index] = imageData[index];

                var imageBlob = new Blob(buffer);
                imageBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                imageBlob.name = /\/([^\/]+)$/.exec(imageElement.src)[1];

                return imageBlob; // A `File`-like `Blob` object.
            };
    })();
```

Usage:

```
getFilelikeBlobFromImageElement(document.getElementById("imgProfile"));
```

[To get the `Blob` from a `<canvas>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228552/serialize-canvas-content-to-arraybuffer-and-deserialize-again)

[To make a `Blob` `File`-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused with the File API,  if the image already exists in the server, all left from you to do is to declare an `<img>` tag with a reference to the image URL and to display it:

```
<img src="serverAddress\yourImage.png" alt="Image Something" />
```

Comment: But it doesn't seem like previewing is what he wants. He already have the file uploaded on the server and just wish to display it. So I think he has confused the example with what he wants to do.